# Question about the value of individual items given the value of an entire set

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, expected-value

I have kind of an interesting and fun question I encountered today and I'm unsure how the derive the answer.

So let's say I have a mystery box that's worth $120 for 10 items. You are able to get repeats and each item is independent of the next.

There are 9 common items, 7 rare items, and 4 epic items in total.

Individually, each item has a 57.4%, 29.7%, and 12.9% chance to drop a common, rare, or epic item, respectively.

What is the value for each individual item (i.e. each individual common, rare, and epic item)?

So I tried an approach finding the weighted value of each item relative to the draw by doing:

$\sum_ {}= \frac{\frac{1}{P(x)}}{\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{1}{P(x)}}$

So it's taking each weighted inverse probability to get the odds of each item. (i.e. for the commons, $\frac{1}{.574} = 1.742$, for the rares, $\frac{1}{.297} = 3.367$, and for the epics, $\frac{1}{.129} = 7.752$, so $ \sum_{x=1}^n\frac{1}{P(x)} $ = 12.861, meaning each individual weight is .1355, .2618, and .6027, for commons, rares, and epics, respectively.

Then I said the value for each individual item (averaged out to $12/item, since 120 for 10), would be

12*.1355 = 1.625

12*.2618 = 3.142

12*.6027 = 7.233

for commons, rares, and epics, respectively. And this is where I'm kind of stuck. This definitely doesn't make sense, as each item is worth less than the average cost per item. I think I just need a different formula to use and was just kind of brainstorming ideas.

What's the correct way to approach this? And how does (or does) there being x amount of each common, rare, or epic item affect the average value per item?

I think I just need a fresh set of ideas or someone who knows a little more about statistics to help me answer this question, thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand why we should assume differing values.  Why not every item be worth \$12?  "*How does there being x amount of each... affect the average value per item?*"  It doesn't unless you want it to.  There is no agreed upon formula here... if you want there to be a specific outcome, *you decide what the formula is*... no one else can.

Comment: In practice, with trading card games and the like, the value of a particular card will indeed be influenced some by the rarity... but more importantly the value will be influenced by the playability of the card and supply-and-demand for the card.  There are plenty of trash mythic-rare cards in MTG that are worth less than certain commons in the same set, so it is a fallacy to assume all mythic-rares (*or epics as the case may be*) should all hold the same value.

Comment: What if the value of these items were directly correlated to their respective rarities, such as in a market of supply and demand where these items were being sold/distributed, and you need to figure out the value of each item based on that?